Smoothness of the action of the deck transformation group
In page 163 of John M Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" (second edition), for a given smooth covering map $\pi:E\to M$, when the author proves the smoothness of the action of the deck transformation group $\textrm{Aut}_\pi(E)$ on $E$ (Proposition 7.23), which is a map $\textrm{Aut}_\pi(E)\times E\to E$ given by $(\varphi, e)\mapsto\varphi(e)$, he said in the errata that "Replace the last line of the proof of Prop. 7.23 by “The action is smooth because each $\varphi$ can be written locally as a composition of a smooth local section followed by $\pi$".
I am not sure how a diffeomorphism $\varphi:E\to E$ can be locally written as a composition of a smooth local section followed by $\pi$. I think I missed something very obvious here...
On the other hand, I tried to find some other books which give a proof of the smoothness of the map $\textrm{Aut}_\pi(E)\times E\to E$, but I couldn't find any. So, any reference is appreciated.

The errata need an erratum. The $\pi$ there should be some choice of a local inverse of $\pi$ (which is smooth).

It should be (locally) $\varphi=s\circ \pi$ (where $s$ is a local section), not the other way around.

Oops, good catch. I've now fixed the correction.

@JackLee Thank you for the correction.

I don’t know what is your level of familiarity with the topic, so at the risk of sounding dull, I’ll review even basic concepts.
I think it should be relatively obvious if you really think of what a "section" means in this context.
In case you don't know, a section is defined as a right inverse of $\pi$.
Basically, you have $\pi \colon E \to M$; you know that $\pi$, as in any covering map, is a surjective mapping, and it is never bijective (unless the covering is very stupid (i.e. $E$ is diffeomorphic to $M$).
So in principle $\pi$ should not admit inverses, since it is not a bijection.
However, maps such as $\pi$ do allow so-called one-sided inverses.
A (smooth) map $ j \colon M \to E$ such that $\pi \circ j = \mathrm{Id}_M $ is called a right inverse for $\pi$, or a section.
Notice that since $\pi \circ j = \mathrm{Id}_M$ is bijective, we deduce that  $j$ must be injective. I am not super sure about this detail, maybe someone else could verify it, but I guess $j$ is also a Smooth Embedding of $M$ into $E$.
In order to understand how such a section $j$ might operate, I suggest you start with what is called a trivial covering, such as "a stack of pancakes".

You have the base (in this case $U$) and then you have the total space, which stores many discrete copies of $U$, one stacked over the other; these are called sheets. You should convince yourself that a section $j$ would operate as an embedding, by brining the base to perfectly match one of the copies.
A trivial covering is one in which $E$ is just the disjoint union of $M$ a certain number (possibly infinite) number of times.
For non-trivial coverings, the situation is not so different after all.
I'm not sure whether you already know this, but deck transformations are diffeomorphism $\varphi \colon E \to E$ that basically "shuffle the sheets" around. That's why they're called deck transformations. Because ideally, they are exactly like shuffling a deck of cards (when the covering is trivial, like the one in the picture).
We've said that $\pi \circ j = \mathrm{Id}_M$; but what about $j \circ \pi$? Can we say that it is $\mathrm{Id}_E$? Well, if $\pi$ and $j$ were bijective, yes, of course. But this is not the case. As a matter of fact, it will take you one second to realize that the composition $j \circ \pi$ will precisely produce a deck transformation. Pick a point from one sheet, then apply $\pi$, and you will be brought to the corresponding point on the base space. Then apply $j$, which will embed the base space into one sheet, which possibly a different sheet than the one you started from. You should convince yourself that all of the decks transformations of a trivial covering are of this form. This should settle John Lee's claim.
What about non-trivial coverings?
Well, things could be different, but the point is that in the definition of covering we explicitly require the covering be locally trivial. So even if for non-trivial coverings the deck transformations may not be of this form, when you work on a small patch, things works precisely as before.
A piece of advice: when studying coverings, I've always found it useful to learn a notion or test something on trivial coverings first, and then on some simple non trivial coverings. My best advice, the infinite covering $\mathbb R \overset{\pi}{\to} \mathbb S^1$. If you're not familiar with how it works, here are two short YouTube videos.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmce8ykBu1k&pp
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vP7NAeeKjrw

Sorry, are you claiming the formulation is correct, after multiple folks in the comments (including the book's author) have said it is not?
